# API Documentation On Docsify?

Tags: docsify

What's the "best" way to display API Documentation on doscify?
I currently use gitbook, which looks like this, https://file.coffee/u/0l-TVj93mr.png
But I want to migrate to docsify so I can have more control over my docs.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've custom done it using TABS and a bit of markdown. Image: [image]

##### GET Bot Stats

```
https://statcord.com/logan/stats/:bid
```

This endpoint allows any user to get data that Statcord has recieved from your bot. (If bot is marked as private, this endpoint **WILL NOT** work.)

##### Request

**Path Parameters**

| Name | Type | Description | Required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| botid | string | Your Bot's Discord ID. | The ID of the Discord Bot you would like to get stats for. |

##### ** Response **

**200: OK**

Stats successfully retrieved.

```js
{
    error:false,
    data:[]
    popular:[]
}
```

**400: Bad Request**

Bot stats were unable to be retrieved.

```js
{
    error:true,
    message:"Some parameters are incorrect or missing. API Docs --> https://docs.statcord.com/api"
}
```